# Mysql - combine rows with matching value

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Let's assume my table looked like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `verify` (
`1id` varchar(111) DEFAULT NULL,
`1email` varchar(111) DEFAULT NULL,
`2id` varchar(111) DEFAULT NULL,
`2time` varchar(111) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `verify` (`1id`, `1email`) VALUES ('79843', 'email@example.com');
INSERT INTO `verify` (`2id`, `2time`) VALUES ('79843', '120');
```

Which looks like this:

```
+-------+-------------------+-------+-------+
| 1id   | 1email            | 2id   | 2time |
+-------+-------------------+-------+-------+
| 79843 | email@example.com | NULL  | NULL  |
| NULL  | NULL              | 79843 | 120   |
+-------+-------------------+-------+-------+
```

And I would like to somehow combine the rows with matching `1id` and `2id` column, so that the resulting table looks like

```
+-------+-------------------+-------+-------+
| 1id   | 1email            | 2id   | 2time |
+-------+-------------------+-------+-------+
| 79843 | email@example.com | 79843 | 120   |
| NULL  | NULL              | 79843 | 120   |
+-------+-------------------+-------+-------+
```

What I have tried so far:

```
UPDATE `verify` set 2time = 2time where 2id like 1id;
```

However, that doesn't affect any rows.

Do you have any tips?

Comment: To my knowledge you cannot use LIKE like that, it's for string matching.

Comment: @cjs1978 it can be used but it 'shouldn't' be used for integers!

Comment: @AliRasheed I think you need to cast the integer as a char or varchar first, ... WHERE CAST(ColumnName as CHAR) LIKE "100"

Comment: Gees, just use `\`2id\` = \`1id\``.  And don't use names starting with digits!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is just comparing and assigning columns in the same row of the table, not comparing across different rows. There's no rows where `2id like 1id` is true, so it doesn't change anything; and even if it did, `set 2time = 2time` wouldn't do anything, since it's just copying a column to itself.

You need to join the table to itself so you can relate different rows.

```
UPDATE verify AS v1
JOIN verify AS v2 ON v1.1id = v2.2id
SET v1.2time = v2.2time, v1.2id = v2.2id
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c1c04)